# How can I add a button inside DetailView template that sends ID to a form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a App called "Properties" and I've created a DetailView that is working. Inside my Properties models I have a Property model and a Bedroom model with a ForeignKey to Property.

```
#views.py 
   class PropertyDetailView(DetailView):
        template_name = 'properties/property-detail.html'
        model = Property

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            contacts = ContactsOwner.objects.filter(owner__property=self.object)
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['contact'] = contacts
            return context
```

My models.py:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    property_reference = models.CharField(db_column='Property_Reference', max_length=10)  # Field name made lowercase.
    address = models.CharField(db_column='Address', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    post_code = models.CharField(db_column='Post_Code', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, choices=HOUSE_TYPE_CHOICES)  # Field name made lowercase.
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField(db_column='Bedrooms', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    bathrooms = models.IntegerField(db_column='Bathrooms', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    usual_cleaning_requirements = models.CharField(db_column='Usual_Cleaning_Requirements', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    notes = models.CharField(db_column='Notes', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    feature_image = models.ImageField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Property'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.property_reference

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("properties:property_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


class Bedroom(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(db_column='Type', choices=BEDROOM_TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=50)
    bed_dimensions = models.CharField(db_column='Bed_Dimension', choices=BED_DIMENSION_CHOICES, max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    ensuite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    notes = models.CharField(db_column='Notes', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bedroom')
```

What I need is to create a button named "Add Bedroom" inside the template "property-detail.html" that sends me to a form with pre filled Foreign Key. Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect that button submit to a view that gets the required info you want and then redirect that to another template with context the info you received (your Foreign key per se)

Comment: Have you got any example where I can see this in practise?